# How can I load the last nine created nodes?

Tags: nodes, 9

I want to get the latest nine nodes in a preprocess hook. I am using the following code, but it returns all the *news* nodes.

```php
$entities = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadByProperties(['type' => 'news']);
```

Is it possible to load only the last nine created nodes using `loadByProperties()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`loadByProperties()` just loads entities given the value of some of their properties. For more complex queries, which (for example) sort the returned nodes basing on some criteria, or return the last X entries, you need to use the object returned by `\Drupal::entityQuery()`.

```php
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->accessCheck(FALSE)
  ->condition('type', 'news')
  ->sort('changed', 'DESC')
  ->range(0, 9);

$nids = $query->execute();
```

`$nids` will contain an array of node IDs you can use to load the nodes, for example with `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($nids)`.

I used `accessCheck(FALSE)` to avoid Drupal would return only the nodes to which the currently logged-in user has access. To let Drupal return only the nodes to which the currently logged-in user has access, that line must be removed.

Comment: excellent answer, thank you for your help

Comment: Isn't the entity type given as  ```->condition('type', 'news')``` ?